# SQL timeout error occurs while connecting to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm running a C# application which repeatedly queries a database on SQL Server 10.50.1617 depending on the input. The SQL queries are embedded resources in the application. In the past it worked fine. Recently we have been getting more frequent SQL "timeout expired" errors, and it is now at the point when the program never completes. I tried changing the logic of how the program connects to the database, so that the queries are smaller but more numerous. This has had no effect.

Furthermore, from debugging I see that the timeouts are occurring at random. For example, sometimes it can't even complete 1 query (one which takes less than 1 second when done directly in SSMS). Other times it will time out at the 900th query.

I've done some research on this topic and found that others have similar problems (e.g., this post: [SQL timeout expired on fast query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324865/sql-timeout-expired-on-fast-query))

It seems like some helpful suggestions were offered, regarding looking at disposing of transactions, etc. However, I think I have a much weaker background in topics like integrating C# (which I'm using through Visual Studio) and a database. So I found the answers on those questions difficult to understand. To make matters worse I am trying to fix this in someone else's code, that I did not originally write.

I'm hoping that someone can offer more of a layman's explanation of some things I might want to look into given that I am receiving this error. I am really new to this and while I do understand most of the terminology I am still wrapping my head around all the moving parts.

What are some aspects of my code that I might want to look at or consider reworking? Is this likely to be an issue with my C# code or might there be some problem with the database (which has grown significantly larger, and continues to do so, since this application was originally written)? Any suggestions are appreciated, and please let me know of any other information I could provide.

```
protected IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> ExecuteQuery(
            string query,
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters,
            IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = null)
        {

            using (DbCommand command = GetCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = query;
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var pair in parameters)
                    {
                        DbParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                        parameter.ParameterName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParameterPrefix)
                            ? pair.Key
                            : ParameterPrefix + pair.Key;
                        parameter.Value = pair.Value == null ? DBNull.Value : pair.Value;
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    }
                }
                using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var dict = comparer == null
                            ? new Dictionary<string, object>(reader.FieldCount)
                            : new Dictionary<string, object>(reader.FieldCount, comparer);
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
                        {
                            dict[reader.GetName(i)] = reader[i] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader[i];
                        }
                        yield return dict;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code in general consists of a lot of different .cs files so I'm not sure what part is most productive to post but here is the function that is called in other places, to execute queries. I thought that is probably the most relevant place to start.

Database commands are called with the 'using' syntax which should theoretically deal with the disposal issue, I thought...

Comment: Can you please supply a portion of the code you are using? Timeouts can occur for a vast number of reasons, one that sometimes effects us is when the server is receiving a lot of connections and/or is in the process of a complex task.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the **Structured Query Language** - a language, not a database product. To help diagnose connection problems, we really need to know what **concrete database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I'm taking a guess that it's SQL Server as the linked question refers to SQL Server.

Comment: Is the timeout occurring on connection or on executing a command?

Comment: Usually when executing a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With queries that time out, there are essentially two solutions.

Firstly you must make sure the timeout is set so that it will only be triggered if something has actually gone wrong, badly enough wrong that you want to abandon the query rather than just wait a little. So for example if queries normally take five seconds you will probably want the timeout to be nearer 30 seconds. If they normally take 30 seconds, you will maybe want a timeout of 2 minutes or more.

Secondly, you must make sure the queries complete in as short a time as possible.

This is not something with a generic answer but there is a lot of advice available for how to make queries run faster. If this is a relatively new application it is probable that little thought has been given to appropriate indexes for example. However the best approach may be different for each query.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not really sure if the structure of the queries themselves is the problem since the timeouts are so random. The timeout is currently set to 30 seconds and when I tested the queries themselves in SSMS they took on average, 1-2 seconds up to a maximum of 10 seconds.